# Pass values of user defined datatype to plsql stored procedure from ADO.net

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am very new to ADO.NET and SQL. I was playing around with oracle and ADO.NET and have ran into a problem which I feel is not documented well.

I have a stored procedure which used a custom type called `NUM_ARRAY` which is defined as follows.

```
create or replace 
TYPE NUM_ARRAY 
AS TABLE OF NUMBER(38, 0);
```

and my stored procedure is as follows.....

```
PROCEDURE SAMPLE_PROCEDURE(
SAMPLE_ARRAY IN NUM_ARRAY)
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE RETURNLIST_PICKLIST_MAPPING 
SET PICKLIST_ID = 5555555 
WHERE RETURNLIST_ID 
IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(SAMPLE_ARRAY));
END SAMPLE_PROCEDURE;
```

I am trying to invoke this stored procedure using the following .NET code

```
idbInterface.Open();

idbInterface.AddParameters("RETURN_LIST_ID_IN", returnListId);
idbInterface.Parameters["RETURN_LIST_ID_IN"].DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int16;
idbInterface.Parameters["RETURN_LIST_ID_IN"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

idbInterface.AddParameters("Cur_Picklist_report", null);
idbInterface.Parameters["Cur_Picklist_report"].DbType = System.Data.DbType.Object;
idbInterface.Parameters["Cur_Picklist_report"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

DataSet dsPickListReportData= idbInterface.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, procedureName);
```

Now the problem is that I am getting a `wrong number or type of arguments` error.

How can I send the a datatype of type `NUM_ARRAY` from ADO.NET code?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. `SAMPLE_ARRAY` is a table. So you will need a `wrapper` type stored procedure to pass these numbers as a comma separated string (varchar) and then call this SP inside your wrapper SP. You may have to do this only if the above SP is used in other places of your system. If not you can change the original SP to accept a comma separated varchar.

Comment: ADO.net is getting a really low view rate nowadays....